# How to rename elk-stack tag to elastic-stack?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I was working with elastic search and the stack for the past few years. Previously, the stack was called `elk-stack` which stands for **Elasticsearch**, **Logstash**, **Kibana**. After the introduction of **Beats** into the stack, the stack is no longer elk-stack and is `elastic-stack`. How can I rename / request to rename, the [elk-stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elk-stack) tag in Stack Overflow? Also, the description about the tag currently is;

> ELK Stack combines the Elasticsearch, Logstash & Kibana to provide
>   realtime insights of any type of structured, unstructured data.

This also need to be changed to include Beats.

Comment: You can edit the tag wiki yourself to update the description.  Just click click "Improve Tag Info" from the tag's question list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elk-stack).  As for renaming, that can only be done by a mod.  Best place is asking a question on meta like this and one will (hopefully) do it.